# Print all the characters separated by a space js

Tags: javascript

i have a variable and I want to separate the name whit a space letter by letter and then UpperCase the letters

var name = "Tom Hanks";

console.log(name) has to be equal to "T O M H A N K S"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the [Help Center topics on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You'll also find a ton of helpful Javascript documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). You probably want `.split()` and `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a new user, I recommend reviewing [ask] for tips on forming your questions. Generally, it is expected you will show what you have tried thus far, and state what specific issue you are facing, in order for the community to help you. When you simply state your requirements, it creates the appearance that you are attempting to rely on SO as a free software-writing platform, or as a homework service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var name = "Tom Hanks";
var result = name.toUpperCase().split("").join(" ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! it works whitout " .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')   "

Answer (score 0):

First you must split the string to separate the letters of the word and save 'em in a array object. For that you can use the `String.split()` function:

```
const myString = 'Tom Hanks';
const splittedString = myString.split('');
```

Then you can use `Array.join()` function to create a new string with spaces between the letters of the previous array:

```
const stringWithSpaces = splittedString.join(' ');
```

Finally you can use the `String.toUpperCase()` to set the "caps lock" on:

```
stringWithSpaces.toUpperCase();
```

So, here is the complete snippet:

```
const myString = 'Tom Hanks';
const splittedString = myString.split('');
const stringWithSpaces = splittedString.join(' ');
const upperCaseStringWithSpaces = stringWithSpaces.toUpperCase();
console.log(upperCaseStringWithSpaces);
```